# Text Match based on looping through values in excel matching value in a txt file with 3 million rows [to slow]

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that loops through all the cells in Column E , it then looks for a match in the text file and enters the first word from the line of text that is matched in the txt file. This works , but when I loop through over 10000 rows , it takes 3 hours to complete.

Just checking if there was a more efficient way of doing this. To speed up the process. Any help would be much appreciated

```
Sub SearchTextFile()
Dim x
Dim hex, reg As String
Dim strsearch As String
x = Sheet9.Range("Q1").Value
Dim hexa As String
Const strFileName = "T:\Hex\Hex_Codes.txt"
hex = Sheet9.Range("P1").Value
reg = Sheet1.Range("E" & x).Value
If Right(reg, 1) = "-" Then GoTo err
strsearch = hex
Dim strLine As String
Dim f As Integer
Dim lngLine As Long
Dim blnFound As Boolean
f = FreeFile
Open strFileName For Input As #f
Do While Not EOF(f)
lngLine = lngLine + 1
Line Input #f, strLine
If InStr(1, strLine, strsearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
Text = Text & strLine
On Error GoTo err
Sheet1.Range("L" & x).Value = Format(Split(Text, ",")(0), "@")
blnFound = True
Exit Do
End If
Loop
Close #f
If Not blnFound Then
End If
err:
End Sub

Sub searchReg()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim lr1
lr1 = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim y
For y = 2 To lr1
Sheet9.Range("P1").Value = Sheet1.Range("E" & y).Value
Sheet9.Range("Q1").Value = y
Call SearchTextFile
Next y
Call verify_text_formulas
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent your code - for you and us. This goes a LONG way in trouble shooting.

Comment: You're opening and closing the txt file for each search. Within each search you're searching line by line. Both of those will stagnate code execution.

Comment: Apart of identing code, it is a best practise to define first the Constants, then the Variables and then put your code. Also... the names for the variables... "Dim x" or "Dim f As Integer" don't help to understand the purpose.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and you'll identify undeclared vars like `Text`.

Comment: Why *hex* and *reg* ? They appear to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a single static read from the text file to avoid repetitive open.read/close calls.

I've removed the use of Sheet8 as a holding/transfer place for values by passing the important and necessary values into the SearchTextFile helper as parameters/arguments.

You provided no information on verify_text_formulas so it is currently commented out.

*hex* and *reg* seemed to be the same thing; *hexa* was never used; *text* was never declared and seemed redundant. I've reduced the use of extraneous variables.

```
Option Explicit

Const cFileName As String = "T:\Hex\Hex_Codes.txt"

Sub SearchTextFile(Optional hex As String, _
                   Optional ln As Long = -1, _
                   Optional closeOff As Boolean = False)

    Static txt As String
    Dim ff As Integer, p As Long, ps As Long, str As String
    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    If txt = vbNullString Then
        'Debug.Print "new read"
        ff = FreeFile(1)
        Open cFileName For Binary As #ff
        txt = Space$(LOF(ff))
        Get #ff, , txt
        Close #ff
        txt = vbLf & txt
    End If

    If closeOff Then
        'Debug.Print "closed"
        txt = vbNullString
    Else
        p = InStr(1, txt, hex, vbBinaryCompare)
        If p > 0 Then
            ps = InStrRev(txt, vbLf, p, vbBinaryCompare)
            str = Chr(39) & Split(Mid(txt, ps + 1, p - ps + 1), ",")(0)
            Sheet1.Cells(ln, "L") = str
            blnFound = True
        End If
    End If

    If Not blnFound Then
    End If

err:

End Sub

Sub searchReg()

    Dim y As Long

    debug.print timer

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.EnableEvents = False

    For y = 2 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        SearchTextFile hex:=Sheet1.Cells(y, "E").Value, ln:=y
    Next y

    SearchTextFile closeOff:=True

    'Call verify_text_formulas

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    debug.print timer

End Sub
```

Post back some timer counts for various record sets if you have a chance. This was tested on a small (30 rows) .TXT file but I would be interested in the time it takes to process larger files.

Comment: Thanks. It now takes just over 5 mins to loop through 1000 rows. Is there a way to export all matches , as my code only matches the first match. As there are some instances where there are more than 1 match. could be up to 5 matches.

Comment: Yes, there is an easy loop for InStr in a Do While Loop by advancing the starting position. Where would you put the additional returns? Column L on the same row is used for the first. Tbh, ~0.333 seconds per search isn't bad but I was expecting something a little better. It must be the sheer size of the TXT that gums it up the search as well as the initial load time.